# remove quotes before an array list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have been strugling with a problem, I am using

```
var srlisthidden = $('#hiddenroutList').val();
```

`srlisthidden` returns an array of list but in quotes `"['0015','0016']"`

```
$.each(srlisthidden, function(i, value) {
});
```

But because of the double quotes on the beginning of the array,it is not allowing the list to iterate even, I tried many different options to remove the double quotes like regEx and

`jQuery.parseJSON('['+srlisthidden+']')`, but none of them worked, Please give me solution.

Comment: How is your input field getting that value in the first place? That's the thing to work on.

Comment: What type of element is `hiddenroutList` and what value are you expecting it to have?

Comment: <input type=hidden value="${modelLocationInformation.location.locationInfo.eachOtherList}" id = "hiddenroutList"/> ,these is a hidden value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var x =  "['0015','0016']"; // The value that you are grabbing
var sol = eval(x); // This returns the value as an array of strings.
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this as well

```
var to_parse =  "['0015','0016']"; 
var array = parse.replace(/\[|]|'/g, '').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires inner quotes around strings be double-quotes escaped with a backslash; the parser doesn't play nicely with single quotes.

Clean up your string with regex:

```
var str = srlisthidden.replace(/\'/g, "\"")
```

Output: `["0015","0016"]` (as a string)

Then parse as JSON:

```
JSON.parse(str)
```

Output: `["0015", "0016"]` (as an array)